# How to effectively control what part of my web page gets printed when I'm using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing, stylesheet

I am working on an HTML page (no server-side scripting) web page with JavaScript.

My page displays a cascading menu of articles to the user.  When the user selects an article, the article is displayed to the user.

I want to program my page so that when the user clicks "Print", only the title and article appear to the user.

I did the following:

1) I wrapped all sections of my page within DIVs with `class='nonPrinterContainer'`.  I created a blank DIV with `class='printerContainer'`.  I added some jQuery JavaScript that does the following whenever a new article is displayed:

1) Set the inner HTML of the `printerContainer` DIV to an empty string.
2) Copy the HTML for the selected title and article to the inner HTML of the `printerContainer` DIV.

Finally, I added a CSS stylesheet to the page:

```
<link type='text/css' rel='Stylesheet' media='print' href="styles/print.css" />

.nonPrinterContainer { display:none; }
.printerContainer { display: block; }
```

At first, this seemed to work great.  I would open the page, click on an article, click print, and only the article title and article would print.  However, to my dismay, I discovered that when the user clicks on one article and then another in a way that makes the menu disappear and then reappear (part of my page logic), the menu then becomes part of the page that prints.

I opened up the page in FireBug and reproduced the error.  When I browse the JavaScript-modified markup code in FireBug, I see that as I expected, only the article title and text appear in the `.printerContainer`.

How can it be that if everything else (including the menu) can be wrapped inside a DIV with `display:none` in the print stylesheet, and yet the menu still prints sometimes.  I also tried adding `#menu { display:none; }` to my print stylesheet to no avail.

I think that this may have something to do with the way I use `jQuery.show()` to display the menu.  But to repeat, this bug only appears when I click on an option that makes the menu disappear and then reappear.

How can I better asset control over what part of my JavaScript-driven page prints?

Answer (score 1):

One technique I've used to to have a hidden Iframe. Copy the content you want to the Iframe, then call `window.print()` from the iframe instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, @Diodeus.  I think I may have found a more suitable solution for my particular issue.

On my page, I had the menu in a div with class `nonPrinterContainer`.  However, I repeatedly called `jQuery.show()` and `jQuery.hide()` on the menu in my script.  This seemed to somehow override my print stylesheet.

The solution I have discovered is to nest the menu inside a seperate div with class `nonPrinterContainer` like so:

```
<div class='nonPrinterContainer'>
    <div id='menu'></div>
</div>
```

instead of

```
<div class='nonPrinterContainer' id='menu'>
</div>
```